# get same value from multiple select dropdown in react js

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown

I won't do to like this. I have a basket and here I have five apples. I want to divide it into five-person. If a user takes 2 items from here. Then the next person will have to be available 3 items. If this person takes 2 items then the basket has only 1 item. The five-user will be like

```
<select>
  <label>userOne</label>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>;
{
  /* userOne selected 2 */
}
<select>
  <label>userTwo</label>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  {/* removed automaticaly 4 and five option */}
  {/* <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option> */}
</select>;
{
  /* userTwo select 2 */
}
<select>
  <label>userThree</label>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  {/* <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option> */}
  {/* 3-2 = 1 */}
</select>;
{
  /* userFour have only one  */
}
<select>
  <label>userFour</label>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  {/* <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option> */}
</select>;
{
  /* userFour already selected one */
}
<select>
  <label>userFive</label>
  <option>0</option>
  {/* userFive have no item available */}
  {/* <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option> */}
</select>;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to filter the list of options depending on the selected data
For this you need to display options dynamically.
Example of such code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const USER_COUNT = 5;
const OPTION_COUNT = 5;
const options = Array(OPTION_COUNT + 1)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => i);

function App() {
  let [users, setUsers] = useState(Array(USER_COUNT).fill(0));

  const handleChange = (idx) => (e) => {
    setUsers(
      users.map((user, userIdx) => {
        if (userIdx < idx) {
          return user;
        }
        if (userIdx === idx) {
          return +e.target.value;
        }
        return 0;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {users.map((user, userIdx) => {
        let prevOptionsSum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < userIdx; i++) {
          prevOptionsSum += users[i];
        }
        let userOptions = options.slice(0, options.length - prevOptionsSum);
        return (
          <div key={userIdx}>
            <label>user {userIdx + 1}</label>
            <select value={user} onChange={handleChange(userIdx)}>
              {userOptions.map((_, userOptionIdx) => (
                <option key={userOptionIdx}>{userOptionIdx}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```